# SELECT DISTINCT return duplicated values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables `players` `positions` `players_national`

I need to `SELECT DISTINCT` positions for `players_national` where player_positon is associated with `players` table.

My Tables are like this:

```
Players Table
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| player_id         player_name     player_team     player_position   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    1               KAKA                12              1
    2               Ronaldo             7               2
    3               Adriano             10              2



Positions Table
-------------------------------------------------------
| position_id         position_name                   |
-------------------------------------------------------
     1                  Midfield            
     2                  Forward         



Players_national Table
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| player_id             player_team         player_national_team  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
     1                       12                         4
     2                       7                          4
     3                       19                         4

My Dream output is this
---------------------------------------------------
| player_national_team          position          |
---------------------------------------------------
          4                         1                           
          4                         2
```

My Query is like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT players. * , positions. * , players_national. * 
FROM players
LEFT JOIN positions ON positions.position_id = players.player_position
LEFT JOIN players_national ON players_national.player_id = players.player_id
WHERE players_national.player_id = players.player_id AND players_national.player_national_team = 4
```

Comment: Well, it's distinct rows, not distinct everything.

Comment: I have 3 rows now in my output, I couldn't make it 2 !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select everything from every table then every row will be `DISTINCT`; you need to limit your `SELECT` clause to just the fields you want to be `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT positions.position_id, players_national.player_national_team
FROM            players
                LEFT JOIN positions ON positions.position_id = players.player_position
                LEFT JOIN players_national ON players_national.player_id = players.player_id
WHERE           players_national.player_id = players.player_id AND players_national.player_national_team = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Distinct player_position on table players, where is join to table players_national

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT(players.player_position),
  players_national.player_national_team
FROM players INNER JOIN players_national;
```

#### result:

```
+-----------------+----------------------+
| player_position | player_national_team |
+-----------------+----------------------+
|               1 |                    4 |
|               2 |                    4 |
+-----------------+----------------------+
2 rows in set
```